# how to insert string line by line in list with python

Tags: python

i want to run the code in every line in this string to get only the value of the driver (c,d,e) and then but them in list
the string

```
1                C           1048576                  30 GB IFS                
2                d           1048576                  30 GB IFS  
1                e           1048576                  30 GB IFS
```

i use that code but i repeat every value of (c,d,e) 3 times in the list

```
d[]
for line in data.split('\n')[1:]:
                    dliver = ouput2[17]
                    print('dliver',dliver)
                    dliver1 = dliver+':'
                    print(dliver1)
                    d.append(dliver1)
                    print('d',d)
```

note data the veritable inside it the value of string

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
for line in data.split('\n')[1:]:
```

you get a variable called `line` that you can work with. But you never do.

If I understand the question correctly, you simply want

```
dliver = line[17]
```

instead of

```
dliver = ouput2[17]
```

Comment: i try it but i have error in this line dliver = line[17] 
  "errorMessage": "string index out of range",

Comment: @rehamadel: then you have a line that is shorter than 17 characters

Answer (score 0):

At first we create a data structure(list) named `output`. Then we iterate over the string. As the last step we are splitting it with spaces and newlines in the list comprehension. At the last we append the second string of the list into the `output` list.

```
output = []
for i in stringer:
    splitted = [x for x in i.split() if x != '']
    output.append(splitted[2])
```